# Driverless AI : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_workers'

Tags: driverless-ai

While working on driverless AI latest version i.e. 1.4.2, we are facing below error - 
we used same data that we were using in version 1.3 and it worked just fine.

```
================================================================================
2019-01-07 12:36:18,275 C:             D:172.8GB M:117.0GB 46209 ERROR  : Experiment hocirika FAILED with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_workers'
2019-01-07 12:36:18,280 C:             D:172.8GB M:117.0GB 46209 ERROR  : ================================================================================

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2633, in h2oaicore.systemutils.traced_func
      File "h2oaicore/auto_dl_support.py", line 6254, in h2oaicore.auto_dl_support.pop_mutate
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_workers'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2912, in h2oaicore.systemutils.find_raise_exception
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2633, in h2oaicore.systemutils.traced_func
      File "h2oaicore/auto_dl_support.py", line 6254, in h2oaicore.auto_dl_support.pop_mutate
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_workers'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "h2oaicore/auto_dl.py", line 2583, in h2oaicore.auto_dl.do_auto_dl
      File "h2oaicore/auto_dl_support.py", line 6066, in suggest_pipeline
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2461, in h2oaicore.systemutils.trace.f
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2640, in h2oaicore.systemutils.traced_func
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2914, in h2oaicore.systemutils.find_raise_exception
      File "h2oaicore/systemutils.py", line 2633, in h2oaicore.systemutils.traced_func
      File "h2oaicore/auto_dl_support.py", line 6254, in h2oaicore.auto_dl_support.pop_mutate
    Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_workers'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue was fixed in the 1.5.0 release: https://www.h2o.ai/download/. Please let us know if you still experience the issue with version 1.5.0 or greater. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Joe, its working fine with the 1.5.1 release.